# How to hide navigation bar permanently in android activity?

Tags: android, fullscreen, navigationbar

I want to hide navigation bar permanently in my activity(not whole system ui).
now i'm using this piece of code

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

It hides the bar but when user touches the screen it showing again. is there  any way to hide it permanently until activity `onStop()`;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permanently hide navigation bar on activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713845/permanently-hide-navigation-bar-on-activity)

Comment: A lot of good and specific details are laid out here, in this official Google/Android link: [Enable fullscreen mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive).

Comment: The flag automatically cleared when user touched the screen according to the documentation. You have to made changes to your UI design to hide navigation bar all the time.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

**Snippets:**

[FullScreenFragment.java](https://gist.github.com/gelldur/cf7ff0d0d026dbd743d0)

[HideNavigationBarComponent.java](https://gist.github.com/gelldur/9c22ab760ebbc976c95b)

---

This is for Android **4.4+**

Try out immersive mode https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Fast snippet (for an **Activity** class):

```
private int currentApiVersion;

@Override
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

    // This work only for android 4.4+
    if(currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    {

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);

        // Code below is to handle presses of Volume up or Volume down.
        // Without this, after pressing volume buttons, the navigation bar will
        // show up and won't hide
        final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView
            .setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility)
                {
                    if((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0)
                    {
                        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
                    }
                }
            });
    }

}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && hasFocus)
    {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

If you have problems when you press Volume up or Volume down that your navigation bar show. I added code in `onCreate` see [setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener](https://gist.github.com/gelldur/cf7ff0d0d026dbd743d0)

Here is another related question:

[Immersive mode navigation becomes sticky after volume press or minimise-restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164836/immersive-mode-navigation-becomes-sticky-after-volume-press-or-minimise-restore)

Comment: When user swipes top/ bottom of the screen,that will display the  Semi-transparent navigation bars temporarily appear and then hide again. IS IT POSSIBLE TO HIDE THAT TOO ?

Comment: @KarthickRamu I found a way, just look at my answer down :)

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat Your hint needs a rooted device :(

Comment: yeah, sry about that :(

Comment: I get this exception: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer.setAlpha(float)' on a null object reference
            at com.android.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.doHide(WindowDecorActionBar.java:822)`

Comment: Thanks for the `gist`, will the navigation bar hide permanently? And i think i need to put all my activity logic in the fragment and show it in the activity?

Comment: @DawidDrozd Thank you, but I have a problem, My activity root layout is RelativeLayout, and it has a child view that is set android:layout_alignParentBottom="true", the navigation bar disappear but the child view doesn't move to bottom edge of the screen, as if the navigation bar is set to invisible not gone, could you help?

Comment: @Jack Probably you need remeasure whole view but not sure. Try to invalidate like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946478/what-triggers-a-views-measure-to-be-called

Comment: If you want to make use of the space that the navigation bar occupied, you have to remove all occurrences of `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from your views. Android Studio includes this attribute when generating some layouts. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42501330/650894

Comment: Hmm, that works, with one caveat: when in my app I press any button that causes a new window to appear on the screen ( 'window' - i.e. a DialogFrament, a PopupWindow, or simply a Spinner's selecttion list window) - then the navigation bar re-appears and stays there until the window in question gets dismissed.
Any cure for that?

Comment: That works but I used only oncreate(){... } part. I didn't integrate the function onWindowFocusChanged and all is working perfectly.

Comment: can we do it for whole application?

Answer (score 77):

Do this.

```
public void FullScreencall() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) { // lower api
        View v = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        //for new api versions.
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
}
```

This works 100% and you can do same for lower API versions, even if it's a late answer I hope it will helps someone else.

If you want this to be permanent, just call `FullScreencall()` inside your `onResume()` method.

Comment: I recommend taking a look at https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html, which explains that your method simply hides the bar until there is interaction and again shortly after interaction is complete.

Comment: It doesn't hide navigation bar (andriod 10 home gesture navigations)

Answer (score 17):

For people looking at a simpler solution, I think you can just have this one line of code in 
`onStart()`

```
  getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION|
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

It's called Immersive mode. You may look at the official documentation for other possibilities.

Comment: I am getting err  ( cannot find symbol 
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);)                                                                                                       ``` @Override
    protected void onStart()
   {
      getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION|
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        super.onStart();
       }```

Comment: This was what worked for me on React Native. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22839594/5305519 was complex + hides the software menu bar leaving a black bar behind blocking the rest of my app. I used it like this `@Override` `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {` `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION|View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);}` in `MainActivity.java` under `public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity` with `import android.view.View; import android.os.Bundle;`

Answer (score 6):

Try this for all android version including **Android 30(R)**.

For more check this class: https://github.com/fiftyonemoon/Rapid/blob/main/rapid/src/main/java/com/fom/rapid/app/UI.java

Show/Hide all system bars:

```
 public void hideSystemUI(Window window) { //pass getWindow();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {

        window.getInsetsController().hide(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars());

    } else {

        View decorView = window.getDecorView();

        int uiVisibility = decorView.getSystemUiVisibility();

        uiVisibility |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE;
        uiVisibility |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        uiVisibility |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            uiVisibility |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE;
            uiVisibility |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        }

        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiVisibility);
    }
}


public void showSystemUI(Window window) { //pass getWindow();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {

        window.getInsetsController().show(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars());

    } else {
        View decorView = window.getDecorView();

        int uiVisibility = decorView.getSystemUiVisibility();

        uiVisibility &= ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE;
        uiVisibility &= ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        uiVisibility &= ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            uiVisibility &= ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE;
            uiVisibility &= ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        }

        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiVisibility);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The other answers mostly use the flags for `setSystemUiVisibility()` method in `View`. However, this API is deprecated since Android 11. [Check my article about modifying the system UI visibility for more information.](https://medium.com/@cernilovsky/modifying-system-ui-visibility-in-android-11-e66a4128898b) The article also explains how to handle the cutouts properly or how to listen to the visibility changes.

Here are code snippets for showing / hiding system bars with the new API as well as the deprecated one for backward compatibility:

```
/**
 * Hides the system bars and makes the Activity "fullscreen". If this should be the default
 * state it should be called from [Activity.onWindowFocusChanged] if hasFocus is true.
 * It is also recommended to take care of cutout areas. The default behavior is that the app shows
 * in the cutout area in portrait mode if not in fullscreen mode. This can cause "jumping" if the
 * user swipes a system bar to show it. It is recommended to set [WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_NEVER],
 * call [showBelowCutout] from [Activity.onCreate]
 * (see [Android Developers article about cutouts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout#never_render_content_in_the_display_cutout_area)).
 * @see showSystemUI
 * @see addSystemUIVisibilityListener
 */
fun Activity.hideSystemUI() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        window.insetsController?.let {
            // Default behavior is that if navigation bar is hidden, the system will "steal" touches
            // and show it again upon user's touch. We just want the user to be able to show the
            // navigation bar by swipe, touches are handled by custom code -> change system bar behavior.
            // Alternative to deprecated SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
            it.systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
            // make navigation bar translucent (alternative to deprecated
            // WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION)
            // - do this already in hideSystemUI() so that the bar
            // is translucent if user swipes it up
            window.navigationBarColor = getColor(R.color.internal_black_semitransparent_light)
            // Finally, hide the system bars, alternative to View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            // and SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN.
            it.hide(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars())
        }
    } else {
        // Enables regular immersive mode.
        // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
        // Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
                // Do not let system steal touches for showing the navigation bar
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                        // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        // Keep the app content behind the bars even if user swipes them up
                        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
        // make navbar translucent - do this already in hideSystemUI() so that the bar
        // is translucent if user swipes it up
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION)
    }
}

/**
 * Shows the system bars and returns back from fullscreen.
 * @see hideSystemUI
 * @see addSystemUIVisibilityListener
 */
fun Activity.showSystemUI() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        // show app content in fullscreen, i. e. behind the bars when they are shown (alternative to
        // deprecated View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
        window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)
        // finally, show the system bars
        window.insetsController?.show(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars())
    } else {
        // Shows the system bars by removing all the flags
        // except for the ones that make the content appear under the system bars.
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your codes with the BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE flag on the emulator, but the navigation bar will pop up and remain displayed when i touch the screen. Any idea what else i should set to get the STICKY functionality on Android 11?

Comment: @AngelKoh You have to call hideSystemUI() manually if you want to hide it. Check the article mentioned in my answer, it contains all these details. Sticky mode means the bars will be transparent if the user swipes them up and the app will receive the touch events as well (see https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive#sticky-immersive).

Comment: yes hideSystemUI() is called and  the Ui got hidden the first time. however when i touch the screen afterwards, the navigation bar pops back out and stays displayed.

Comment: The purpose of BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE is to prevent the system stealing touches and displaying the bars. So I am not sure what could cause this without seeing / debugging the real app.

Comment: @AngelKoh did you found the solution? As you mentioned BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE react to click, not just swipe

Answer (score 4):

Use:-

```
view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

In Tablets running Android 4+, it is not possible to hide the System / Navigation Bar.

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.html#SystemUI)  :

> The SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION is a new flag that requests the
>   navigation bar hide completely. Be aware that this works only for the
>   navigation bar used by some handsets (it does not hide the system bar
>   on tablets).

Answer (score 3):

According to [Android Developer site](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html)

I think you cant(as far as i know) hide navigation bar permanently..

However you can do one trick. Its a trick mind you.

Just when the `navigation bar` shows up when user touches the screen. Immediately hide it again.
Its fun.

**Check this**.

```
void setNavVisibility(boolean visible) {
int newVis = SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;
if (!visible) {
    newVis |= SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
}

// If we are now visible, schedule a timer for us to go invisible.
if (visible) {
    Handler h = getHandler();
    if (h != null) {
        h.removeCallbacks(mNavHider);
        if (!mMenusOpen && !mPaused) {
            // If the menus are open or play is paused, we will not auto-hide.
            h.postDelayed(mNavHider, 1500);
        }
    }
}

// Set the new desired visibility.
setSystemUiVisibility(newVis);
mTitleView.setVisibility(visible ? VISIBLE : INVISIBLE);
mPlayButton.setVisibility(visible ? VISIBLE : INVISIBLE);
mSeekView.setVisibility(visible ? VISIBLE : INVISIBLE);
}
```

See this for more information on this ..

[Hide System Bar in Tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16713845/2026280)

Answer (score 2):

It's my solution:

First, define boolean that indicate if navigation bar is visible or not.

```
boolean navigationBarVisibility = true //because it's visible when activity is created
```

Second create method that hide navigation bar.

```
private void setNavigationBarVisibility(boolean visibility){
    if(visibility){
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        navigationBarVisibility = false;
    }

    else
        navigationBarVisibility = true;
}
```

By default, if you click to activity after hide navigation bar, navigation bar will be visible. So we got it's state if it visible we will hide it.

Now set OnClickListener to your view. I use a surfaceview so for me:

```
    playerSurface.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setNavigationBarVisibility(navigationBarVisibility);
        }
    });
```

Also, we must call this method when activity is launched. Because we want hide it at the beginning.

```
        setNavigationBarVisibility(navigationBarVisibility);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a security issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12605313/1303691

therefore its not possible to hide the Navigation on a tablet permanently with one single call at the beginning of the view creation. It will be hidden, but it will pop up when touching the Screen. So just the second touch to your screen can cause a onClickEvent on your layout. Therefore you need to intercept this call, but i haven't managed it yet, i will update my answer when i found it out. Or do you now the answer already?

Answer (score 1):

I think the blow code will help you, and add those code before setContentView()

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
```

Add those code behind setContentView()
  getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);

Comment: Field requires API level 21+

Answer (score 1):

You can hide Navigator Bar using this:

```
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        if(hasFocus){
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION|
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
            );
        }
    }
```

This way you can hide Navigation Buttons without hiding Status bar

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Comment: NO it's give me same result

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will resolve your issue. Copy and paste this code on your MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                          
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener
    (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {

            if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                hideNavigationBar();
            } 
        }
    });
}



private void hideNavigationBar() {
   getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION|
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
```

It will works on Android-10. I hope it will helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the hide and show system UI for android 11 and Below. But below from Android its deprecated.

```
private fun hideSystemUI() {
            WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
            WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, drawerLayoutID).let { controller ->
                controller.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
                controller.systemBarsBehavior =
                    WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
            }
        }
    
        private fun showSystemUI() {
            WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, true)
            WindowInsetsControllerCompat(
                window,
                drawerLayoutID
            ).show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
        }
    
        private fun hideSystemUIBeloR() {
            val decorView: View = window.decorView
            val uiOptions = decorView.systemUiVisibility
            var newUiOptions = uiOptions
            newUiOptions = newUiOptions or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
            newUiOptions = newUiOptions or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            newUiOptions = newUiOptions or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            newUiOptions = newUiOptions or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
            newUiOptions = newUiOptions or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            decorView.systemUiVisibility = newUiOptions
        }
    
        private fun showSystemUIBelowR() {
            val decorView: View = window.decorView
            val uiOptions = decorView.systemUiVisibility
            var newUiOptions = uiOptions
            newUiOptions = newUiOptions and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE.inv()
            newUiOptions = newUiOptions and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN.inv()
            newUiOptions = newUiOptions and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION.inv()
            newUiOptions = newUiOptions and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.inv()
            newUiOptions = newUiOptions and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY.inv()
            decorView.systemUiVisibility = newUiOptions
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide status and navigation bar using this function

```
    private void hideStatusAndNavBar(){
    requireActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requireActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
           View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY

    );
}
```

and you can show it again by this function

```
  private void showStatusAndNavBar(){
    requireActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requireActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.VISIBLE
            |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
}
```