# How to Hide ActionBar and NavigationBar completely

Tags: android

I knew this question is being asked previously but not getting the accurate solution.
I want to hide ActionBar and NavigationBar from my activity in or order to make it full screen. I tried the below code in my Activities OnCreate Method but its showing Action Bar for some fraction of seconds and than making it full screen. In Galaxy S3 (android 4.3), its even more than a second. so how can I make it completely invisible and my activity as full screen completely from the beginning only.
I saw many apps running on S3 only, but their is no ActionBar, not even for fraction seconds.

```
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {           
         getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    } else {
         getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `onCreate` function of your activity add this code before `setContentView`:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

In `AndroidManifest` file write

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

If the minimum SDK Version of your application is 19 (KitKat), then you have to add an additional piece of code to your `onResume` function:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility
                    ( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY );
```

Answer (score 2):

In AndroidManifest file write

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`

in activity tag

and use

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

befor `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: Using both helped me out. so just replace "or" with "and". Thanks you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` in the declaration of your Activtiy in your Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

try this before setContentView

```
    //Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //Remove notification bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

This [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) and [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724420/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-permanently-in-android-activity) demonstrates `Immersive Full-Screen Mode` which allows your app to go full screen.

***tltr;***

try this snippet which I got from the Android Developer website:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Hopefully I helped!

Comment: Sorry Buddy, But this piece of code also showing ActionBar for fraction of seconds. It didn,t helped me.

Comment: If you haven't already, take a look at the Android Developer post. It might help you.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to write just

```
getActionBar().hide(); (Above Api level 11)
```

or

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();(Up to Api level 8)
```

thats it...