# How to hide navigation bar in Android app?

Tags: android, fullscreen, navigationbar

I was wondering how I could hide the navigation bar in an Android application?

I know how to hide it initially, but as soon as I touch the screen it pops back up. I want to hide it the same way games like Clash of Clans hide it where the only way to make it pop up is by swiping down the notifications or by swiping where the navigation bar should be.

Comment: Do you want to hide the navigation bar in the IDE or in your app?

Comment: In the app but Ganga Naidu answered it. Thanks anyways

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide navigation bar permanently in android activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724420/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-permanently-in-android-activity)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

use immersive mode check this [Immersive mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

```
    // This snippet hides the system bars.
private void hideSystemUI() {
    // Set the IMMERSIVE flag.
    // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the content
    // doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
}

// This snippet shows the system bars. It does this by removing all the flags
// except for the ones that make the content appear under the system bars.
private void showSystemUI() {
    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Comment: I have to wait another 2 minutes to accept as an answer and I can't click the up arrow since I don't have enough reputation

Comment: Thanks so much, it helped hide the bar. However, once I swipe up to reveal the navbar, it doesn't hide itself after awhile like the status bar does. How can I get the navbar to hide itself after the user reinteracts with the game?

Comment: Instead of just IMMERSIVE you use IMMERSIVE_STICKY if you want the navbar to auto hide like the notification bar does.

Comment: I find on certain devices it causes the first touch in the app to be ignored.

Comment: Navigation bar overlap footer layout after called the method showSystemUI

Answer (score 17):

Here it is in the context of the onCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

    }
```

The Android docs have a good explanation of what the different flags do:
[Using Immersive Full-Screen Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

Answer (score 11):

**Just put this method in your activity where you want to hide status bar and navigation bar in sticky mode.**

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    //This is used to hide/show 'Status Bar' & 'System Bar'. Swip bar to get it as visible.
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    if (hasFocus) {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Android Studio does not understand this code, ```View decorView``` flagged red.

Comment: @MarkKortink - `View decorView` is just an object of View class.

Answer (score 5):

the easy way is adding this 2 lines after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: There is one problem: turn screen off and on  and you will see the navigation bar again.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity's onCreate method:

```
this.getWindow()
    .setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
              WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: That only hides it until the user taps the screen

Comment: It doesn't in my app. Does you app have some onClickListener that might change your window flags?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Create An Activity With The Snippet Above,And Then Add Another Windows Above The Layout:

```
LayoutParams layoutParameteres=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        v.setLayoutParams(layoutParameteres);
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams parameters=new WindowManager.LayoutParams(sizeX, sizeY, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        parameters.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
        parameters.x=0;
        parameters.y=0;
        wm.addView(v, parameters);
```

Good Luck With It

Answer (score 0):

### setSystemUiVisibility is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

### you can also use like this:

> Kotlin

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  
    val windowInsetsController =
        WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
    // Configure the behavior of the hidden system bars.
    windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior =
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE

    // Add a listener to update the behavior of the toggle fullscreen button when
    // the system bars are hidden or revealed.
    window.decorView.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { view, windowInsets ->
        // You can hide the caption bar even when the other system bars are visible.
        // To account for this, explicitly check the visibility of navigationBars()
        // and statusBars() rather than checking the visibility of systemBars().
        if (windowInsets.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars())
            || windowInsets.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())) {
            binding.toggleFullscreenButton.setOnClickListener {
                // Hide both the status bar and the navigation bar.
                windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            }
        } else {
            binding.toggleFullscreenButton.setOnClickListener {
                // Show both the status bar and the navigation bar.
                windowInsetsController.show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            }
        }
        view.onApplyWindowInsets(windowInsets)
    }
}
```

> JAVA

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController =
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(getWindow(), getWindow().getDecorView());
    // Configure the behavior of the hidden system bars.
    windowInsetsController.setSystemBarsBehavior(
            WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    );

    // Add a listener to update the behavior of the toggle fullscreen button when
    // the system bars are hidden or revealed.
    getWindow().getDecorView().setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener((view, windowInsets) -> {
        // You can hide the caption bar even when the other system bars are visible.
        // To account for this, explicitly check the visibility of navigationBars()
        // and statusBars() rather than checking the visibility of systemBars().
        if (windowInsets.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars())
                || windowInsets.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())) {
            binding.toggleFullscreenButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                // Hide both the status bar and the navigation bar.
                windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            });
        } else {
            binding.toggleFullscreenButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                // Show both the status bar and the navigation bar.
                windowInsetsController.show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            });
        }
        return view.onApplyWindowInsets(windowInsets);
    });
}
```

Referances : https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/immersive

https://memreaktas.blogspot.com/2024/03/how-to-hide-navigation-a-bar-in-Android-Kotlin.html

Answer (score -2):

Modify this line in the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"
```