# Hide/show status and navigation bar on

Tags: android, gallery, statusbar

I am searching for hours, but nothing found.
I just want to hide/show status and navigation bar when I hit the screen, like android gallery.

```
// Hide status bar
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
// Show status bar
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

The code above works fine for Status bar, but what about navigation bar (bottom bar) like android gallery? (I dont want to use 4.4 immersive mode)

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21724698/4261176