# How can I hide the Navigation bar from android

Tags: android

How can I hide the Navigation bar from android? I can hide the Title Bar from the layout. But when I run the application in device I see the Navigation bar still. Is this possible to hide the Navigation bar?

[image]

Comment: Did you even google this? https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

```
View aView = getWindow().getDecorView();
aView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

but I suggest you to read this first [Link](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html)

and I found this also a worth read [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724420/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-permanently-in-android-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below in your activity:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

See: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use it

```
@Override
```

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

// This work only for android 4.4+
if(currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
{

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);

    // Code below is to handle presses of Volume up or Volume down.
    // Without this, after pressing volume buttons, the navigation bar will
    // show up and won't hide
    final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView
        .setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility)
            {
                if((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0)
                {
                    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
                }
            }
        });
}



@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
if(currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && hasFocus)
{
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
```

}