# Android hide navigation bar from service

Tags: android, navigationbar

I have a service in which, when the user shakes his/her phone, shows a full screen overlay window. I'm using this code to get it done:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
mOverlayView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay, null);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
wm.addView(mOverlayView, params);
```

It fills up the whole screen, EXCEPT for the navigation bar. Is there a way I can hide the navigation in my service that displays the overlay?

Note that my app is running in the background. The user may be running any other app in the foreground, and I want to show my full screen overlay window even if my main activity is not running.

All examples I could find online all seem to require an activity running...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724420/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-permanently-in-android-activity

Comment: the link you suggested requires `public class HideNavigationBarComponent extends Fragment`. Since I'm not running an activity, I don't think I can use that...

Comment: did you try all the given answer.

Comment: @Tauqir no, I didn't, but since I'm not the foreground activity, do you think it will work? I have no place I can insert that fragment... I just have an overlay view...

Comment: Any service can only be launched via intent either in `Activity` or `fragment`. try there.

Comment: @Tauquir the thing is: I have a service that runs in the background. Meanwhile users can switch to another app and shake the phone to access the overlay service. My app may not and will not be on foreground on most cases.

Comment: Ok. It seems that we've some serious issue then.

Comment: But do you think it's possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91678/discussion-between-tauqir-and-joao-lourenco).

Comment: try immersive mode (https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

Comment: @Randyka Yudhistira it doesn't work for me since as I told Tauqir, my app may not be running in the foreground

Comment: then you need root permission to edit a system file