# the hidden Navigationbar is appeared when toolbar menu button is clicked

Tags: android, uinavigationbar

I have used the method presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21724420/3990512) to hide Navigationbar. It works properly but when I tap the context menu button (three vertical points in the right side of the toolbar), the navigationbar is appeared again.

I have used the code:

```
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

in `onResume()`, `onCreate()`, `onOptionsItemSelected()`, `onWindowFocusChanged()`.

If all of menu items are set to `app:showAsAction="always"` the Navigationbar is never appeared but when some are shown in the list, it appeard.

Comment: can i ask you about some screens?

Comment: I didnt undrestand what you mean, whould you please explain?

Comment: I mean that some images describing the problem are higly appreciated