# How to hide system buttons panel on Android?

Tags: android

I need to switch to full-screen mode in runtime (player app) and return back on user click, so it should hide android system bar (at the top) and back,apps,menu software buttons panel too (at the bottom).

How can i hide bottom panel with software buttons?

PS. I'm already using `getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);` but it does not help:

[image]

Comment: like [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/system-ui/immersive.html) ?

Comment: seems to be what i need, i'm going to try it

Comment: no, using `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN` does not hide software buttons panel

Comment: You mean the right image's black section? check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22839594/4409113

Comment: correct, the right black panel

Comment: @4ntoine - Check that example in my answer, especially, the latest part for different apis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to Official documentation.

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Please see http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html and http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility.html

Comment: also you need to add IMMERSIVE flag

Answer (score 0):

Using `Immersive Full-Screen Mode` seems to be good.

Also, there is an example of how to do that: http://developer.android.com/samples/ImmersiveMode/project.html

And check this `Fragment`: http://developer.android.com/samples/ImmersiveMode/src/com.example.android.immersivemode/ImmersiveModeFragment.html

Which they used:`decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();`

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        final View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(
                new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int i) {
                        int height = decorView.getHeight();
                        Log.i(TAG, "Current height: " + height);
                    }
                });
```

**And here you can see how it's working for different version(APIs):**

```
/**
     * Detects and toggles immersive mode (also known as "hidey bar" mode).
     */
    public void toggleHideyBar() {

        // The UI options currently enabled are represented by a bitfield.
        // getSystemUiVisibility() gives us that bitfield.
        int uiOptions = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
        int newUiOptions = uiOptions;
        boolean isImmersiveModeEnabled =
                ((uiOptions | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY) == uiOptions);
        if (isImmersiveModeEnabled) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Turning immersive mode mode off. ");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Turning immersive mode mode on.");
        }

        // Navigation bar hiding:  Backwards compatible to ICS.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
            newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
        }

        // Status bar hiding: Backwards compatible to Jellybean
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        }

        // Immersive mode: Backward compatible to KitKat.
        // Note that this flag doesn't do anything by itself, it only augments the behavior
        // of HIDE_NAVIGATION and FLAG_FULLSCREEN.  For the purposes of this sample
        // all three flags are being toggled together.
        // Note that there are two immersive mode UI flags, one of which is referred to as "sticky".
        // Sticky immersive mode differs in that it makes the navigation and status bars
        // semi-transparent, and the UI flag does not get cleared when the user interacts with
        // the screen.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
            newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        }

        getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(newUiOptions);
    }
```