# Hide Navbar space when using nav drawer in android marshmallow

Tags: android, user-interface, navbar

I have been trying this for a long time.

In my activity I have a nav drawer which will by default enable the `toolbar`. What I want to achieve is to hide the status bar and the nav bar but show the toolbar.

When I set the `uiOptions` as:

```
uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE;
```

It works fine in Android *Kitkat* and *Lollipop* but when it comes to Marshmallow, what happens is that the `statusBar` and the nav bar gets hidden but the navbar space is left behind.

How do I remove it in **Marshmallow**?

Snap shot:
[image]

Comment: If you are lazy to type a question i am lazy to answer as well

Comment: I am new to asking questions in stackoverflow... So if i have made any mistake excuse me... If you know a solution plz help me with it...

Comment: Got the solution here: [Navigation bar hides but leaves space when using navigation drawer in android 5+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41198934/navigation-bar-hides-but-leaves-space-when-using-navigation-drawer-in-android-5#answers)