# Android: Lock navigation bar as Keypad lock screen does

Tags: android, security

I've been trying to lock the navigation bar on Android for 3 weeks so that the user can't send my activity to background. I need to do this to get my lock screen app more secure (I know that writing a custom lock screen is not the best idea but it's a requirement).

I've tried immersive mode, system dialogs, flags on decor view, onKeyDown, onBackPressed (this one works for the back button), reorder_tasks and moving my task to the front (this only works when I click on recent apps) and the usage API.

I've found this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wow.keypad.lock.screen which does EXACTLY what I need to do but I don't know how they did it.

Could anyone please help me?

I need a permanent solution like the one these guys from WOW have done.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

[How To Hide Navigation Bar Permanently In Android Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22839594/2104990)

It looks like something like this has already been tackled. Your main task would not be to lock the nav bar, as much as just hide it so that the user cannot access it.