# How to hide this Navigation bar in Android studio While Editing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I added nav bar in my app. But after adding nav bar It's visible in Editor view and I can't edit My Content below this nav bar.

How to hide this Nav bar?

image :

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724420/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-permanently-in-android-activity

Comment: Not like this,i want to hide while editing in Android studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue

in `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` add this `tools:openDrawer="end"`

it will hide nav bar during editing in the android studio.

Answer (score 1):

In the xml add on your root layout , i suppose that it's a DrawerLayout, the attribute : `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

Then in your Toolbar layout add the attribute `tools:visibility="invisible"`

`tools` allow you to set value only visible on the editor.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

While Editing Use This

```
nav.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```