# How to hide navigation bar when edittext is focused in immersive mode

Tags: android, android-immersive, android-navigation-bar

I am developing a single-use device with **Android**. HW has a full keyboard but no main keys (Back, Home, Overview).
Some of the app should be working in immersive mode and they contain `EditText` fields.
When the app is in immersive mode (I used Lock Task Mode), if I select `EditText` field, a black bar with the same size of the navigation bar, pops up from the bottom.
I cannot set **`qemu.hw.mainkeys=1`** because it removes nav bar completely but I need it for some other apps.
Is there any way I can hide it for `EditText` in just some cases?
I have access to a full AOSP source.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/22839594/6142219

Answer (score 0):

You can't, Android does not allow you to focus an EditText without showing the Navigation Bar. (except if you are using an external keyboard)

Probably because some people don't know how to unfocus it and need to press the back button.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. I've been looking into the same thing, as I almost exclusively use a floating keyboard, and the black bar that gets shown when it's open is incredibly annoying (gesture navigation with no indicator would usually remove it, but enabling the Fold 4 taskbar brings it back). I use SystemUI Tuner to force immersive mode everywhere, and on some apps (e.g. Discord) if you switch out and back into the app while the keyboard is open, the keyboard will remain open, but after moment the navigation bar hides itself as if the keyboard weren't open. This suggests it's possible.