# BottomNavigationView is adding space for hidden System Navigation Bar?

Tags: android

In my activity I'm hiding the System Navigation Bar, but I'm adding a BottomNavigationView for fragment navigation. The problem lies with BottomNavigationView adding the space for the System Navigation Bar under itself... how can I remove that space?

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/teal_200"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/teal_200"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment_container"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724420/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-permanently-in-android-activity

Comment: I don't want to hide it permanently... if the user swipes up the the nav bar overlaps the bottomnavigationview that's fine.