# Is there a simple way to hide the Navigation Bar in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

In the android studio, you can easily remove the status bar by adding a line in the themes.xml file.

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

This simple one-line code will hide the status bar. If the user touches the top part of the screen, it appears but after 1 or 2 seconds it disappears again. Is there a similar way to achieve the same effect for the navigation bar?

I know this question has been answered previously but those methods are deprecated and I want to know if there is a simple solution like mentioned above? I am using Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1.

Here is my build.gradle file

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: For what reason do you want to hide the nav bar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide navigation bar permanently in android activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724420/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-permanently-in-android-activity)

Comment: @Omega_Pixel Is not this method deprecated now?

Comment: my answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate` method for your activity you can use:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val actionBar: ActionBar = getSupportActionBar() //Get action bar reference
        actionBar.hide() //Hide the action bar
    }
```

Comment: I know this question has been answered previously but those methods are deprecated and I want to know if there is a simple solution like mentioned above?

Comment: Have you tried the`hideSystemBars` function?

Comment: I'm pretty sure if its in the docs and it says >Last updated 2022-06-21 UTC. then its probably not deprecated. :/