# Completely hiding navigation bar (not only buttons) in android

Tags: java, android

I am using "Navigation Drawer Activity" template from latest Android Studio (2021.2.1 Patch 2) as a start.

How can I hide navigation bar completely? Following code only hides the buttons but navigation bar's white background still exists.

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Thanks.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724420/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-permanently-in-android-activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply this code in `onCreate()` of your activity :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            if (window != null) {
                window.decorView.windowInsetsController!!.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
                window.decorView.windowInsetsController!!.hide(
                    WindowInsets.Type.statusBars() or WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars()
                )
            }
        } else {
            val decorView = window.decorView
            val uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            decorView.systemUiVisibility = uiOptions
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

java version:

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(getWindow(), false);
getWindow().getInsetsController().hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
```