# Delete bottom space from BottomSheetDialog

Tags: android, dialog

How to show dialog without space below ?

[image: Bottom space]

Here code to show dialog:

```
BottomSheetDialog mBottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
   View sheetView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bottom_dialog, null);
   mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(sheetView);
   mBottomSheetDialog.show();
```

Here Style.xml to set dialog style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/BottomSheetDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="NoBackgroundDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="BottomSheetDialog" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/bottomSheetStyleWrapper</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="behavior_hideable">true</item>
    <item name="behavior_peekHeight">500dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724420/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-permanently-in-android-activity

Answer (score 0):

What was written in the article in the comments gave me some thoughts. This navigation can of course be removed by flags, but it is removed with a delay of about 1 second, but there is empty space under it.
So I read other similar answers and just painted the panel white.

```
    View decorView = mBottomSheetDialog.getWindow().getDecorView();
    mBottomSheetDialog.getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(R.color.white);
mBottomSheetDialog.getWindow().setNavigationBarDividerColor(R.color.white);
    
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                       decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
                    }
```